# Symfony 4 - Not rendering Twig Template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

When trying to render a Twig Template within a Symfony 4 project I'm getting an error. I don't know which is the problem. This is the code generating the error:

```
return $this->render('templates/imagenes/index.html.twig');
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

LogicException
You can not use the "render" method if the Templating Component or the Twig Bundle are not available.

Should I install Twig via composer apart Symfony itself?

Comment: yes, you should

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks @gogaz Installing twig did the trick.

```
composer require twig
```

Comment: for me this did not help

Comment: I can leave this comment for whom need to solve this is if that reply doesn't helped to him:
composer require symfony/twig-bundle

Answer (score 1):

and you should not need the templates directory, so just 'imagenes/index.html.twig'

Answer (score 0):

```
 return $this->render('templates/imagenes/index.html.twig');
```

Create the project using this command

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton-website project_name
```

No need to install twig,etc

Answer (score 0):

A guy named Simon Wald-burger mentioned in the lesson's comments that installing "debug" fixed the issue (it fixed it for me). The instruction was in the next lesson.

`composer require debug --dev`

iiirxs is also correct, to output dump in twig file, do

```
{{ dump(variable) }}
```