# You can not use the "render" method if the Templating Component or the Twig Bundle are not available

Tags: php, symfony, twig

You can not use the "render" method if the Templating Component or the Twig Bundle are not available. Try running "composer require symfony/twig-bundle".

```
class RecordsController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="single_page")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function singlePageAction()
    {
        return $this->render('single_page.html.twig', []);
    }
}
```

[Symfony 4 - Not rendering Twig Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743256/symfony-4-not-rendering-twig-template)

Same as for this guy but accepted answer does not help.

Tried also

```
composer require debug --dev
```

then got error

[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package debug.

Did you mean one of these?
symfony/debug
tracy/tracy
maximebf/debugbar
cakephp/debug_kit
symfony/debug-pack

so installed symfony/debug. Which does not make any sense but I did. Of course it did not fix the problem.

Here is how composer.json now looks:

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.13",
        "twig/twig": "~2.10",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/debug": "^4.3"
    }
}
```

I have installed twig 2 because otherwise could not install twig-bundle - was gettig error.

How to get rid of this error and show the template?

**Update:**
Noticed that my application has 2 composer.json files. One in root, another in myapp folder. Guess this is why after install it does not see because it is installed in that root directory. But now I am too angry and tired already to check, will need to do that later.

Answer (score 0):

in order to use twig, after installing the package with composer, you should enable the bundle for your environment(s). Here you have the docs for the current version of symfony https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html

Once you do that, you have to inject twig in your AbstractController.

If you already did all of these steps, I suggest you to add some more code, in order to allow the community to spot the problem.

I also suggest you to avoid using multiple composer.json files: use just one in your project root directory.

Goodbye!